# PhoneGap list autopopulated, show single post

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I would need help with the logic behind one code.

in my phonegap application I am automatically populating list of news. When the user clicks on particular article I want it to show it in different page. I just dont knwo how to pass the id of the article to another page.

ANy ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Local Storage. It's a key/value pair association.

Learn more about that in this sites:

1. http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_webstorage.asp
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage

Example:

```
// In the first page
localStorage.setItem("articleID", articleID);

...
// Then in the other page
var articleID = localStorage.getItem("articleID");
```

Comment: You can also use URL parameters. So when you link to the other page, you may use a form of: detail.html?id=X. Then use code to handle detail.html loading and parse out the query string.